# Java Cerrar segunda Ventana

Tags: java, eclipse

Necesito ayuda ,quiero cerrar una ventana secundaria desde un botón pero no me funciona ,si lo hago desde la misma clase donde esta el .setVisible(true) primario si me funciona pero como el botón lo tengo en otra class ,quisiera saber si alguien me podria decirme como solucionar este fallo

```
class Accion_Cancelar implements ActionListener{        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Pantallas Pantalla=new Pantallas();Pantalla.Pantalla_Antes_Del_Traslado();
            Pantalla.setVisible(false);
            Pantalla.dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificarle al JFrame que tienes activo, que hacer cuando lo mandes a cerrar con dispose().

setDefaultCloseOperation() te permite decidir que hacer, segun la opcion seleccionada:

```
JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE — Salir de la aplicacion.
JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE — Ocultar el JFrame, Pero mantiene la aplicacion ejecutandose.
JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE — Cierra el JFrame, pero mantiene la aplicacion activa.
JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE — Ignora la operacion de cerrar el JFrame.
```

Comment: si eso lo tengo;                                                                                          public void Pantalla_Antes_Del_Traslado() {
  Toolkit Ventana = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Dimension DimensionesDeLAPantalla = Ventana.getScreenSize();
  int AlturaPantalla = DimensionesDeLAPantalla.height;
  int AnchoPantalla = DimensionesDeLAPantalla.width;
  setSize(AnchoPantalla /2, AlturaPantalla);
  setLocation(0,0);
  setResizable(true); 
  setTitle("cliente");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  }

Comment: Haz una cosa, tienes que tener una referencia de la ventana activa. Por ejemplo si con un boton abres la ventana conserva la variable del JFrame pero declarala global al inicio de la clase, ya que posteriormente como tienes la referencia la puedes cerrar con otro boton.